# How to set a Task or Communication in Compucorp new CiviCase

Tags: civicase, activity

After creating new **Activity Type** either **Task** or **Communication**, I cannot see them in the Option for new Task or Communication. Even after the Caches cleared, the Task remains empty and Communication shows the 4 basic options (Email, Follow Up, Meeting and Phone Call).
Is there something to add in the database ?
Thanks for the help using this great new CiviCase ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Silly of me. I forgot about the very clever and granular way that CiviCRM is built. Just creating a new Activity Type was not enough to have it activated in the right CiviCase.
After creating a new Activity Type (either Task or Communication), we must add these new Activities to the right Case Type that can be customised.
And voilà, it's set !